# Sequence-like function which reports all the errors

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a function in the standard library with a signature similar to this one:

```
Traversable f => f (Either e a) -> Either [e] (f a)
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
(Traversable f, Monoid e) => f (Either e a) -> Either e (f a)
```

The idea is to collect the errors instead of failing when the first error is encountered.

I saw that my function looked very much like `sequence` and I was hoping that there was already a typeclass that modelled this pattern.

Comment: haskell noob here, what does `=>` mean?

Comment: @NooneAtAll It separates a context from the rest of the type. See https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html for more details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`Validation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-1.1.1/docs/Data-Validation.html#t:Validation) data type for that. From the documentation:

> [A] `Validation` is either a value of the type `err` or `a`, similar to `Either`. However, the `Applicative` instance for `Validation` *accumulates* errors using a `Semigroup` on `err`. In contrast, the `Applicative` for `Either` returns only the first error.

E.g.:

```hs
> sequenceA [Failure [1], Success "Test", Failure [2] :: Validation [Int] String]
Failure [1, 2]
```

Comment: Yes this seems like the way `Either`'s `Applicative` ought to work, to match `Const` and refuse to throw away any information (unless the type tells it to).  It's an old decision, I hope we'd know better today...

Comment: @luqui a problem is that the monad laws prescribe that the monadic `ap` (`p >>= \f -> q >>= \x -> return (f x)`) must be the same as `<*>`. But that is not compatible with this accumulating behavior of the errors. So `Validation` is not actually an instance of `Monad`.