# When running 'sequence' on a list of Eithers, how does ghc know which argument to list-ify?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have two functions, and I'm confused about how the sequence knows which argument to put into a list, and what actually happens with the Lefts in the Either

```
getMonStat :: T.Text -> IO (Either CmdError MonStat)
..
getMonStats :: [T.Text] -> IO (Either CmdError [MonStat])
getMonStats ms = do
  monStats <- mapM getMonStat ms
  pure $ sequence monStats
```

My questions are:

1. Why does this work? After the mapM, I have `monStats :: [Either CmdError MonStat]`. Running sequence on `[m a]` turns it into `m [a]`.  Why isn't the initial type `[m a b]` since `CmdError` is a type as well? And if `CmdError` is a type to consider, how does ghc know to pick `MonStat` instead of `CmdError` to list-ify? Or with types: why does sequence convert to `m a b -> m a [b]` instead of `m a b -> m [a] b`?
2. Which Left from `[Either CmdError MonStat]` would the final `CmdError` in `Either CmdError [MonStat]` be? The first? A concated string of all of them? I could test but I'm curious in the why as well.

Thank you for any insights into this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Type applications are curried too, and they associate to the left: `[m a b] = [(m a) b] = [m' b]` where `m' = m a`. So it always takes the last argument to "list-ify".
2. It takes the first `Left` in the list. That is the way the `Monad` instance for `Either` is defined: `Left x >>= _ = Left x`. The `sequence` function uses that `Monad` instance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937556/sequence-like-function-which-reports-all-the-errors) about collecting all failures.